# AWS Glue Job Run continuously

Tags: aws-glue

I want to run a Glue ETL job continuously (i.e. start automatically when previous execution of the same job finishes)

a cron trigger won't help because job doesn't always take the same time to finish.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Can't you simply create an EventBridge rule that triggers a job run whenever the job is completed? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-serverless-event-driven-workflow-with-aws-glue-and-amazon-eventbridge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a lambda function that:

1. Runs the glue job (in the body of the lambda). That would look something like this:

   ```
   import boto3 

   client = boto3.client('glue') 
   jobname = 'your glue job'
   response = client.start_job_run(JobName=jobname)
   ```
2. Is triggered when the glue job runs successfully (with an eventbridge trigger that looks at the glue job state change for the relevant glue job(s))

Refer to these docs: [Automating AWS Glue with CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/automating-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-events.html)

Let me know if this helps!